# Quick way to change between no auto formatting and auto formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a method to quickly switch between an Excel state that disables all auto formatting (for ETL work) and the standard state with standard auto formatting  enabled.

There are many posts on how to turn off AF, I'm wondering if there is any method to make this a 1 click operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the macro recorder, turn off auto formatting via the options, stop the macro recorder. Store the macro in your Personal.xlsb and assign a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Sounds good.  I wonder if you would need to make one in reverse to do the opposite?